# Background property CSS3 in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I want the following code to work in safari but it doest not :(

```
background: 
 linear-gradient(75deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 36.5% 0,
 linear-gradient(-75deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 63.5% 0,
 radial-gradient(rgba(127,127,127,0) 49%, rgba(255,255,255,.7) 51%, #c9c9c9 52%);
```

It seems to be working fine in chrome and firefox but not in safari. I have tried webkit and all but it just makes it worse.

Any ideas?

Class:

```
.part a {
width: 200%; height: 200%;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px dimgrey, inset 0 0 4px white;
transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(-15deg);
-ms-transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(-15deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-60deg) rotate(-15deg); 

    background: linear-gradient(75deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-      
    repeat 36.5% 0,
    linear-gradient(-75deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 63.5% 
    0, radial-gradient(rgba(127,127,127,0) 49%, rgba(255,255,255,.7) 51%, #c9c9c9 52%);

background-size: 15% 15%, 15% 15%, cover;
line-height: 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current example is not fully supported by **current** and **older** versions of **Safari**.

You will need to add the `-webkit-` property in order to support 5.1 and 6.

See http://caniuse.com/css-gradients

Use this instead.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(75deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 36.5% 0, -webkit-linear-gradient(-75deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 63.5% 0, radial-gradient(rgba(127,127,127,0) 49%, rgba(255,255,255,.7) 51%, #c9c9c9 52%);
background: linear-gradient(75deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 36.5% 0, linear-gradient(-75deg,transparent 50%, grey 50%, transparent 54%) no-repeat 63.5% 0, radial-gradient(rgba(127,127,127,0) 49%, rgba(255,255,255,.7) 51%, #c9c9c9 52%);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. I tried that already but it does not seem to work. Can you check in your browser? or does it have to do with other properties defined before or after it?

Comment: @Fred It worked for me. There must be something else causing this problem then. If you can provide a URL or some additional HTML/CSS I can help.

Comment: nvm I think I found out what's the problem. It has to do with the link reference.

Comment: @Fred for the stylesheet?